# Restricting picture box movement inside panel

Tags: c#

i am creating a game application in c#, there is panel and picturebox inside that panel. now i want to restrict that picture box within that panel boundary. i am moving picture box with keydown event.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
         {


            pictureBox1.Left -= 10;


               //po = position.Left;
         }

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {


            pictureBox1.Left += 10;
           // po = position.Right;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            pictureBox1.Top -= 10;
           // po = position.Up;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            pictureBox1.Top +=10;
           // po = position.Down;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You've stated your intent.  However, you haven't stated your question.  Your question must be clear and must show that you've exhausted all other means before asking it here.   Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to check the distance between the picture and the boundary of the panel.

Comment: pictureBox1.Left = Math.Max(0, pictureBox1.Left - 10);  You can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred that you use a **switch** statement in your case.

The below code is tested and working. You just need to set the Max values calculated from the height/width of the **PictureBox** and **Panel**.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int borderMargin = 5;
    int stepSize = 10;    

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        {
            int newLeft = Math.Max(0, pictureBox1.Left - stepSize);
            pictureBox1.Left = newLeft;
            break;
        }
        case Keys.Right:
        {
            int maxVal = panel1.Width - pictureBox1.Width - borderMargin;
            int newLeft = Math.Min(maxVal, pictureBox1.Left + stepSize);
            pictureBox1.Left = newLeft;
            break;
        }
        case Keys.Up:
        {
            int newTop = Math.Max(0, pictureBox1.Top - stepSize);
            pictureBox1.Top = newTop;
            break;
        }
        case Keys.Down:
        {
            int maxVal = panel1.Height - pictureBox1.Height - borderMargin;
            int newTop = Math.Min(maxVal, pictureBox1.Top + stepSize);
            pictureBox1.Top = newTop;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also set the `borderMargin` and `stepSize` according to your needs based on your `Form` configuration.